# SQL insert into select auto increment variable

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am a newbie in SQL. Please bear with me. Thanks

I wanna to insert records into a table name `t1` where some of the fields in
those records are from temp table `@t2`.

```
create table t1
(
    transid             varchar(15) not null primary key,
    content             varchar(1000),
    userid              int not null,
    dtcreate            datetime not null,
)

DECLARE @seqno INT = 1;

DECLARE @t2 TABLE ( userid INT, content VARCHAR(1000), dtcreate DATETIME)
```

Let's say i have 10 records in `@t2`

I want to insert into t1 for all the records in @t2(temp table)

```
INSERT INTO t1 (transid,content,userid,dtcreate)
SELECT (CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), dtcreate, 112)+RIGHT('0000'+CONVERT(VARCHAR, ( 
@seqno =+ 1)), 5)) , content, userid, dtcreate FROM @t2
```

This is where the `@seqno =+ 1` does not allow me to do that. How can i do it if i want something like this? Thanks guys. I'm a super newbie.

Comment: Create a sequence, and select the next value from it in your insert statement to generate an incremental value.

Comment: Good job for providing table definitions, even better if there were INSERTs for sample records.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like [ROW_NUMBER](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql) can do this.

An abstract example:

```
DECLARE @T1 TABLE (ID INT)
DECLARE @T2 TABLE (ID INT, VALUE INT)
INSERT INTO @T1 VALUES (1), (4)
INSERT INTO @T2 SELECT *, (ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ID))+100 FROM @T1
SELECT * FROM @T1
SELECT * FROM @T2
```

Applying that to your code:

```
declare @t1 table
(
    transid             varchar(15) not null primary key,
    content             varchar(1000),
    userid              int not null,
    dtcreate            datetime not null
)

DECLARE @t2 TABLE ( userid INT, content VARCHAR(1000), dtcreate DATETIME)

INSERT INTO @t1 (transid,content,userid,dtcreate)
SELECT (CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), dtcreate, 112)+RIGHT('0000'+CONVERT(VARCHAR, ( 
row_number() over(order by userid))+100), 5)) , content, userid, dtcreate FROM @t2
```

One issue I recognize, is that you cannot omit `ORDER BY`, hopefully that's not a problem.

Answer (score 1):

use a [ROW_NUMBER](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql)

example:

```
            DECLARE @t2 TABLE
                (
                  content VARCHAR(10) ,
                  userid INT ,
                  dtcreate DATETIME
                )


            INSERT  INTO @t2
                    ( content, userid, dtcreate )
            VALUES  ( 'A', 20, '2017.01.01' ),
                    ( 'B', 21, '2017.01.02' ),
                    ( 'C', 22, '2017.01.03' ),
                    ( 'D', 23, '2017.01.04' )

            ;
    WITH    CTE
              AS ( SELECT   ctr ,
                            content ,
                            userid ,
                            dtcreate
                   FROM     ( SELECT    ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY userid ASC ) ctr ,
                                        content ,
                                        userid ,
                                        dtcreate
                              FROM      @t2
                            ) T
                 )
        ---INSERT  INTO t1
        ---     ( transid ,
        ---       content ,
        ---       userid ,
        ---       dtcreate
        ---     )
                SELECT  ( CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), dtcreate, 112) + RIGHT('0000'
                                                                  + CONVERT(VARCHAR, ctr),
                                                                  5) ) transid ,
                        content ,
                        userid ,
                        dtcreate
                FROM    CTE
```

Result:

```
        transid         content    userid      dtcreate
        --------------- ---------- ----------- -----------------------
        2017010100001   A          20          2017-01-01 00:00:00.000
        2017010200002   B          21          2017-01-02 00:00:00.000
        2017010300003   C          22          2017-01-03 00:00:00.000
        2017010400004   D          23          2017-01-04 00:00:00.000
```

Answer (score 0):

firstly you create your table like this

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (
  transid INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  content Varchar(1000),
  userid INT Not Null,
  dtcreate DateTime not null,
  PRIMARY KEY (Transid)
)
AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;
```

above query give you autoincrement in your table 
than used query like this

```
INSERT INTO t1 (transid,content,userid,dtcreate)
SELECT transid,content,userid,dtcreate
FROM @t2
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a row_number() function in place of @seqno

```
INSERT INTO #t1 (transid,content,userid,dtcreate)
SELECT (CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), dtcreate, 112)+RIGHT('0000'+CONVERT(VARCHAR, ( 
ROW_NUMBER()over(order by (Select 1)))), 5)) , content, userid, dtcreate FROM @t2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @seqno INT = 1;

DECLARE @t2 TABLE ( userid INT, content VARCHAR(1000), dtcreate DATETIME)
INSERT INTO @t2 ( content, userid, dtcreate )
SELECT 'AA',1,'2017-01-05'
SELECT  @seqno = ROW_NUMBER()OVER(Order by  transid)+1 From t1

--SELECT @seqno

INSERT INTO t1 (transid,content,userid,dtcreate)
SELECT (CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 112)+RIGHT('0000'+CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), (@seqno)), 5)) As seqno 
, content, userid, dtcreate FROM @t2

SELECT * from t1
```

Below is OutPut

```
transid         content userid  dtcreate
-------------------------------------------------------
2017052200001   AA       1      2017-01-05 00:00:00.000
2017052200002   AA       1      2017-01-05 00:00:00.000
2017052200003   AA       1      2017-01-05 00:00:00.000
2017052200004   AA       1      2017-01-05 00:00:00.000
```